# Ban IP's trying to access specific file possible?

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables, fail2ban

Is it possible to ban a user (IP) if that IP tries to access a specific file?

I had a site who was hacked and sent out spam. The compromised files have now been cleaned/removed.

I still get a lot of 404's from IP's trying to access some of those files e.g. /libraries/legacy/form/field/help.php - a file not normally part of the CMS (joomla), so I know for a fact, that if an IP is trying to access this file, they have bad intentions :-)

Is it possible to create a ban rule for all IP's trying to access this file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create mod_sec rules to block the access for that file and configure mod_sec with the fail2ban

Here are the one mod_sec rules to block specific file acces.

```
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "@rx FILE-NAME" \
"phase:2,block,severity:2,msg:'Blocking access to FILE-NAME files.'"
```

And you can setup mod_sec with fail2ban. Please have a look. http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_with_ModSecurity2.5